# Why ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes() is not a static method?

Tags: c#

I am learning about encoding in C#, and I don't understand why `ASCIIEncoding.GetBytes()` is not defined as a static method, I mean why is it necessary to create an `ASCIIEncoding` instance to use it!

Comment: You answered your own question.  You need to create an instance because the method is not static.  If you are looking for an explanation of the architecture and design - StackOverflow is not the place to ask.

Comment: Surprisingly I find that no close reason matches this question. I also find it to be valid, even if asked carelessly.

Comment: @usr I tend to find this opinion-based. There's no other answer than _"Because the framework designers thought this'd be the proper way to define it"_.

Comment: @CodeCaster but they did not flip a coin. There are reasons they did it this way. Those are objective.

Comment: @CodeCaster Your answer is 100% correct and it shows an objective reason why it's designed like this, so I don't see how the question is, itself, subjective. I don't find it any more subjective than OOP is subjective.

Comment: @usr sure there are reasons for this specific case, but we can't know those as we didn't design the framework. The more general question, _"Why implement an instance method instead of a static method"_ has been answered before (polymorphism, for one).

Comment: For convenience, the `Encoding` class has properties for common encodings, `Encoding.ASCII` in particular. But, if you want control over what happens if the string contains characters that can't be represented in ASCII, use [GetEncoding(
 string name,
 EncoderFallback encoderFallback,
 DecoderFallback decoderFallback
)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89856k4b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ASCIIEncoding` is not the only kind of encoding. There is also `UnicodeEncoding`, `UTF8Encoding`, etc.

They all derive from the abstract base class `Encoding` and `GetBytes` is defined in that base class. This allows you to receive any kind of `Encoding` (without knowing the exact kind at compile time) and still be able to call `GetBytes`, with the correct logic being resolved at runtime.

`static` methods cannot be inherited, overridden and invoked using this kind of dynamic dispatch (known as polymorphism).

Answer (score 2):

Because then you couldn't write a method that works with any encoding:

```
public byte[] GetBytes(string input, Encoding encoding)
{
    return encoding.GetBytes(input);
}
```

And that's about how it's used in the framework in various places.

Answer (score 2):

This is done because static methods cannot be used to override virtual methods.

`GetBytes` is a `virtual` method of `Encoding`, the base class of `ASCIIEncoding`. In order to override the method in its base class `ASCIIEncoding` must declare it as an instance method.

If you are using `ASCIIEncoding` a lot, make a static readonly variable in your class to avoid creating new instances of the class:

```
private static readonly Encoding ASCII = new ASCIIEncoding();
...
var res = ASCII.GetBytes(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an API design question. Encodings form a class hierarchy with inheritance in heavy use. That's the overall design and it forces `GetBytes` to be an instance method. The point is that you can make an algorithm use any encoding at all by typing variables as `Encoding`.

It would be possible to provide this method as a static method as well (probably under a different name). The framework authors chose not to do that, probably in order to not create confusion. You could do this yourself now after the fact.